# YouTube Reporting API Bulk Data Content Owner Reports

Tags: api, youtube, reporting

When I call YouTube Reporting API reportTypes.list (https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/v1/reference/rest/v1/reportTypes/list) method for the channel that I am the owner of, the only report types returned are for Channel Reports (https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/v1/reports/channel_reports). What do I need to do to get Content Owner Reports as well? If I need to have Content Owner ID what are the steps for setting it up?

Thank you!